# How to delete folder of owner/group 99 99

Tags: linux, groups, chmod, permissions

I am using wordpress with wp-super-cache plugin. This plugin automatically created a cache folder in my site for storing the cached files.

But unusually it created folder with owner/group 99 99. It was created automatically.

Due to this, i am not able to delete that folder or change the CHMOD of that folder. This really a headache. I searched google, but none gave me a good answer.

Please help me delete or change the CHMOD of that folder ?

I am on Linux server.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. How is it that you're able to see the owner and group if you don't have ssh access? If you have shell access and can `chown` files, why can't you do `sudo chown` or `su` to root and `chown` the directory?

Comment: I saw this owner/group in the owner/group column of the Filezilla FTP software

Answer (score 2):

Root should be able to delete it not matter what. If you want to be able to delete it as another user, you can [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) it to whatever user and group you would like.

Comment: I am the admin of my site and i have access to delete other files and folder.

Comment: @Aakash - Ok, so log in via ssh, su to root and delete it.

Comment: Sorry, my site is not featured with SSH !

Comment: @Aakash - So, if you can't SSH into your server how do you administer it?

Comment: #MarkM usually, i use cpanel to change/view some site settings and Filezilla to transfer the files i from desktop to server.

Comment: @Aakash - then call your host and have them do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a guess that the "sticky" bit is set on a directory above. I would need more info to try help solve this. 
Do a `ls -la && id` and post the results

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SFTP access? Unlikely if you don't have SSH as the port is probably closed, but possible if it's just a shell restriction. Try logging on port 22 using SFTP as root and you should be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As MarkM said..root can do the job.

If you are admin of your website/domain on a linux server but you can only admin it via cPanel or FTP I can imagine that your site is hosted on a shared server and not on a dedicated server.

If it is true... I think you have to open a ticket for assistanse at your provider requesting the chmod or deletion of that files/directory.